# Revoke shared folders in windows

Tags: windows, networking, directory, shared, smb

Over the last few months/years, I have shared a folder or two with numerous people on my domain. How do I easily revoke those shares to keep access to my system nice and tidy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using computer management (an MMC snap-in. See Control Panel Administrative tools) you can see a list of all folders that are shared. You could delete the shares or change the permissions on the share to only allow access for certain people or groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this via the command line:

> C:>net share share-name /d

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, go to:

```
Administrative Tools > Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares
```

This page lists all shares and lets you remove them easily, in one place.